# Check if less than 7 days before ending

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to figure out how to warn a player if their trial period is about to end. I would like to give them a heads up about 7 days before.

Here is what I have so far:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

string currDate = now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
string trialDate = "20190320104842"; // This is how dates are saved in the DB

DateTime addDays = now.AddDays(-7);
string headupDate = addDays.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");


if (System.Int64.Parse(currDate) > System.Int64.Parse(trialDate))
{
    print("TIME RAN OUT");
} 
else if( // NOT SURE WHAT TO USE HERE // )
{
    print("TIME RUNS OUT IN 7 DAYS");
}
else
{
    print("TIME STILL RUNNING");
}
```

Not sure how to calculate if time is within the 7 day limit?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Don't use strings, stick with DateTime till the end

Comment: `DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact("20190320104842", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);` is a useful bit of code.

Comment: DateTime should _not_ save as string in the database. Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: @Enigmativity - Thanks :-)

Comment: @Mansa - Did you work it out?